# How to pass an object to Web Service from its hosting Windows Service

Tags: c#, web-services, object, windows-services

I have a web service, say `MyWebService`, and I need to host it on a windows service, say `MyWindowsService`. So in `OnStart` method in `MyWindowsService`, I start `MyWebService`. When `MyWindowsService` starts, I need to send a log message (from within `MyWindowsService`) to a listener saying the application has been started. Such a log message is generated by a `LogGenerator`.

In `MyWebService`, it also needs to send log messages to the listener as well when certain events are triggered, and those log messages (sent from within `MyWebService`) are also generated by `LogGenerator`.

The `LogGenerator` has a few properties to be configured. Now I am facing some issues.

1. I do not know whether I need to construct an instance of `LogGenerator`, configure this instance in `MyWindowsService`, then pass it to `MyWebService`. If so, then how I can pass an object to the web service from its hosting windows service. Or,
2. I construct an instance of `LogGenerator` in `MyWindowsService` and then I construct a second one in `MyWebService`, so I do not need to pass any object to the web service. Or,
3. I can make `LogGenerator` and all its properties and methods static, so I do not need to create any instances at all. If so, is it thread safe when I create log messages?

Thank you for any input !!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the singleton pattern when starting the web service to identify it and add event listeners on the windows service. Of course, this only works if you have only one instance of the web service.